# HTML, why aren't columns staying in a row? Bootstrap

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/48rq37o3/)

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6 input-group input-group-lg" style="padding-left:15px;">
        <span class="input-group-addon add-on"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></span>
        <input class="form-control" id="daterange" type="text" placeholder="Run Range"
        maxlength="128" readonly="readonly" style="background-color:White;cursor:pointer;" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg has-spinner" id="btn-search">Go!</button>
    </div>
</div><br>
```

I have literally dozens of other instances of rows and columns in my site but this row refuses to behave. Why?

Comment: it has something to do wit the input-group class, if i take it out the button goes on the same line.

Comment: separate the classes in your first nested div. Nest your span and input into another div with input-group and input-group-lg. I believe there is an issue with having those three classes together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*input-group* class in Bootstrap is displayed as a block element, so it will push anything after it to a new line. If you want the button to be next to the input field, you need to add a class for example *input-group-inline* and override the default style from Boostrap.

```
.input-group-inline {
   display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your fiddle is missing a reference to `bootstrap.css`, i added it and it all works fine https://jsfiddle.net/ujbh3z4p/ try checking the references in your html

Answer (score 0):

Remove padding from a row. This can cause to rows to be different widths.